# RSyntaxTextArea not showing line numbers

Tags: java, rsyntaxtextarea

I'm using RSyntaxTextArea for a minimized IDE I'm working on, Everything seems to be really working smoothly except for the line numbering, which I couldn't really make it show:

```
                RSyntaxTextArea textArea = new RSyntaxTextArea(20, 60);
                textArea.setSyntaxEditingStyle(SyntaxConstants.SYNTAX_STYLE_C);
                textArea.setCodeFoldingEnabled(true);
                textArea.setAntiAliasingEnabled(true);
                RTextScrollPane sp = new RTextScrollPane(textArea);

                  sp.setLineNumbersEnabled(true);

                  sp.setFoldIndicatorEnabled(true);
                  if ( sp.getLineNumbersEnabled() )
                  {
                      System.out.println("Enabled"); // it prints the line but it's not showing 
                  }

                  contentPane.add(/*textEditorScrollPane*/ textArea, BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

I can't figure out why it's not showing the line numbers..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not showing the scrollbars either, right? Assuming that `contentPane` is where you want your components, you need to add the `RTextScrollPane` instance to the `contentPane`, not the RSyntaxTextArea instance. The Gutter, which displays line numbers, is a part of the `RTextScrollPane` - an extended `JScrollPane`.

If you don't add a scroll pane to your GUI, it will not be shown, nor will you be able to scroll around. :P

So try the following:

```java
contentPane.add(sp, BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can use the following class:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.Border;
import javax.swing.border.CompoundBorder;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import javax.swing.border.MatteBorder;
import javax.swing.event.CaretEvent;
import javax.swing.event.CaretListener;
import javax.swing.event.DocumentEvent;
import javax.swing.event.DocumentListener;
import javax.swing.text.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.beans.PropertyChangeEvent;
import java.beans.PropertyChangeListener;
import java.util.HashMap;

/**
 * This class will display line numbers for a related text component. The text
 * component must use the same line height for each line. TextLineNumber
 * supports wrapped lines and will highlight the line number of the current
 * line in the text component.
 * <p>
 * This class was designed to be used as a component added to the row header
 * of a JScrollPane.
 */
public class TextLineNumber extends JPanel
        implements CaretListener, DocumentListener, PropertyChangeListener
{
    public final static float LEFT = 0.0f;
    public final static float CENTER = 0.5f;
    public final static float RIGHT = 1.0f;

    private final static Border OUTER = new MatteBorder(0, 0, 0, 2, Color.GRAY);

    private final static int HEIGHT = Integer.MAX_VALUE - 1000000;

    //  Text component this TextTextLineNumber component is in sync with

    private JTextComponent component;

    //  Properties that can be changed

    private boolean updateFont;
    private int borderGap;
    private Color currentLineForeground;
    private float digitAlignment;
    private int minimumDisplayDigits;

    //  Keep history information to reduce the number of times the component
    //  needs to be repainted

    private int lastDigits;
    private int lastHeight;
    private int lastLine;

    private HashMap<String, FontMetrics> fonts;

    /**
     * Create a line number component for a text component. This minimum
     * display width will be based on 3 digits.
     *
     * @param component the related text component
     */
    public TextLineNumber(JTextComponent component)
    {
        this(component, 3);
    }

    /**
     * Create a line number component for a text component.
     *
     * @param component            the related text component
     * @param minimumDisplayDigits the number of digits used to calculate
     *                             the minimum width of the component
     */
    public TextLineNumber(JTextComponent component, int minimumDisplayDigits)
    {
        this.component = component;

        setFont(component.getFont());

        setBorderGap(5);
        setCurrentLineForeground(Color.RED);
        setDigitAlignment(RIGHT);
        setMinimumDisplayDigits(minimumDisplayDigits);

        component.getDocument().addDocumentListener(this);
        component.addCaretListener(this);
        component.addPropertyChangeListener("font", this);
    }

    /**
     * Gets the update font property
     *
     * @return the update font property
     */
    public boolean getUpdateFont()
    {
        return updateFont;
    }

    /**
     * Set the update font property. Indicates whether this Font should be
     * updated automatically when the Font of the related text component
     * is changed.
     *
     * @param updateFont when true update the Font and repaint the line
     *                   numbers, otherwise just repaint the line numbers.
     */
    public void setUpdateFont(boolean updateFont)
    {
        this.updateFont = updateFont;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the border gap
     *
     * @return the border gap in pixels
     */
    public int getBorderGap()
    {
        return borderGap;
    }

    /**
     * The border gap is used in calculating the left and right insets of the
     * border. Default value is 5.
     *
     * @param borderGap the gap in pixels
     */
    public void setBorderGap(int borderGap)
    {
        this.borderGap = borderGap;
        Border inner = new EmptyBorder(0, borderGap, 0, borderGap);
        setBorder(new CompoundBorder(OUTER, inner));
        lastDigits = 0;
        setPreferredWidth();
    }

    /**
     * Gets the current line rendering Color
     *
     * @return the Color used to render the current line number
     */
    public Color getCurrentLineForeground()
    {
        return currentLineForeground == null ? getForeground() : currentLineForeground;
    }

    /**
     * The Color used to render the current line digits. Default is Coolor.RED.
     *
     * @param currentLineForeground the Color used to render the current line
     */
    public void setCurrentLineForeground(Color currentLineForeground)
    {
        this.currentLineForeground = currentLineForeground;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the digit alignment
     *
     * @return the alignment of the painted digits
     */
    public float getDigitAlignment()
    {
        return digitAlignment;
    }

    /**
     * Specify the horizontal alignment of the digits within the component.
     * Common values would be:
     * <ul>
     * <li>TextLineNumber.LEFT
     * <li>TextLineNumber.CENTER
     * <li>TextLineNumber.RIGHT (default)
     * </ul>
     *
     * @param currentLineForeground the Color used to render the current line
     */
    public void setDigitAlignment(float digitAlignment)
    {
        this.digitAlignment =
                digitAlignment > 1.0f ? 1.0f : digitAlignment < 0.0f ? -1.0f : digitAlignment;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the minimum display digits
     *
     * @return the minimum display digits
     */
    public int getMinimumDisplayDigits()
    {
        return minimumDisplayDigits;
    }

    /**
     * Specify the mimimum number of digits used to calculate the preferred
     * width of the component. Default is 3.
     *
     * @param minimumDisplayDigits the number digits used in the preferred
     *                             width calculation
     */
    public void setMinimumDisplayDigits(int minimumDisplayDigits)
    {
        this.minimumDisplayDigits = minimumDisplayDigits;
        setPreferredWidth();
    }

    /**
     * Calculate the width needed to display the maximum line number
     */
    private void setPreferredWidth()
    {
        Element root = component.getDocument().getDefaultRootElement();
        int lines = root.getElementCount();
        int digits = Math.max(String.valueOf(lines).length(), minimumDisplayDigits);

        //  Update sizes when number of digits in the line number changes

        if (lastDigits != digits)
        {
            lastDigits = digits;
            FontMetrics fontMetrics = getFontMetrics(getFont());
            int width = fontMetrics.charWidth('0') * digits;
            Insets insets = getInsets();
            int preferredWidth = insets.left + insets.right + width;

            Dimension d = getPreferredSize();
            d.setSize(preferredWidth, HEIGHT);
            setPreferredSize(d);
            setSize(d);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Draw the line numbers
     */
    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {
        super.paintComponent(g);

        //  Determine the width of the space available to draw the line number

        FontMetrics fontMetrics = component.getFontMetrics(component.getFont());
        Insets insets = getInsets();
        int availableWidth = getSize().width - insets.left - insets.right;

        //  Determine the rows to draw within the clipped bounds.

        Rectangle clip = g.getClipBounds();
        int rowStartOffset = component.viewToModel(new Point(0, clip.y));
        int endOffset = component.viewToModel(new Point(0, clip.y + clip.height));

        while (rowStartOffset <= endOffset)
        {
            try
            {
                if (isCurrentLine(rowStartOffset))
                {
                    g.setColor(getCurrentLineForeground());
                } else
                {
                    g.setColor(getForeground());
                }

                //  Get the line number as a string and then determine the
                //  "X" and "Y" offsets for drawing the string.

                String lineNumber = getTextLineNumber(rowStartOffset);
                int stringWidth = fontMetrics.stringWidth(lineNumber);
                int x = getOffsetX(availableWidth, stringWidth) + insets.left;
                int y = getOffsetY(rowStartOffset, fontMetrics);
                g.drawString(lineNumber, x, y);

                //  Move to the next row

                rowStartOffset = Utilities.getRowEnd(component, rowStartOffset) + 1;
            } catch (Exception e)
            {
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    /*
     *  We need to know if the caret is currently positioned on the line we
     *  are about to paint so the line number can be highlighted.
     */
    private boolean isCurrentLine(int rowStartOffset)
    {
        int caretPosition = component.getCaretPosition();
        Element root = component.getDocument().getDefaultRootElement();

        if (root.getElementIndex(rowStartOffset) == root.getElementIndex(caretPosition))
        {
            return true;
        } else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    /*
     *  Get the line number to be drawn. The empty string will be returned
     *  when a line of text has wrapped.
     */
    protected String getTextLineNumber(int rowStartOffset)
    {
        Element root = component.getDocument().getDefaultRootElement();
        int index = root.getElementIndex(rowStartOffset);
        Element line = root.getElement(index);

        if (line.getStartOffset() == rowStartOffset)
        {
            return String.valueOf(index + 1);
        } else
        {
            return "";
        }
    }

    /*
     *  Determine the X offset to properly align the line number when drawn
     */
    private int getOffsetX(int availableWidth, int stringWidth)
    {
        return (int) ((availableWidth - stringWidth) * digitAlignment);
    }

    /*
     *  Determine the Y offset for the current row
     */
    private int getOffsetY(int rowStartOffset, FontMetrics fontMetrics)
            throws BadLocationException
    {
        //  Get the bounding rectangle of the row

        Rectangle r = component.modelToView(rowStartOffset);
        int lineHeight = fontMetrics.getHeight();
        int y = r.y + r.height;
        int descent = 0;

        //  The text needs to be positioned above the bottom of the bounding
        //  rectangle based on the descent of the font(s) contained on the row.

        if (r.height == lineHeight)  // default font is being used
        {
            descent = fontMetrics.getDescent();
        } else  // We need to check all the attributes for font changes
        {
            if (fonts == null)
            {
                fonts = new HashMap<>();
            }

            Element root = component.getDocument().getDefaultRootElement();
            int index = root.getElementIndex(rowStartOffset);
            Element line = root.getElement(index);

            for (int i = 0; i < line.getElementCount(); i++)
            {
                Element child = line.getElement(i);
                AttributeSet as = child.getAttributes();
                String fontFamily = (String) as.getAttribute(StyleConstants.FontFamily);
                Integer fontSize = (Integer) as.getAttribute(StyleConstants.FontSize);
                String key = fontFamily + fontSize;

                FontMetrics fm = fonts.get(key);

                if (fm == null)
                {
                    Font font = new Font(fontFamily, Font.PLAIN, fontSize);
                    fm = component.getFontMetrics(font);
                    fonts.put(key, fm);
                }

                descent = Math.max(descent, fm.getDescent());
            }
        }

        return y - descent;
    }

    //
//  Implement CaretListener interface
//
    @Override
    public void caretUpdate(CaretEvent e)
    {
        //  Get the line the caret is positioned on

        int caretPosition = component.getCaretPosition();
        Element root = component.getDocument().getDefaultRootElement();
        int currentLine = root.getElementIndex(caretPosition);

        //  Need to repaint so the correct line number can be highlighted

        if (lastLine != currentLine)
        {
            repaint();
            lastLine = currentLine;
        }
    }

    //
//  Implement DocumentListener interface
//
    @Override
    public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent e)
    {
        documentChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent e)
    {
        documentChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent e)
    {
        documentChanged();
    }

    /*
     *  A document change may affect the number of displayed lines of text.
     *  Therefore the lines numbers will also change.
     */
    private void documentChanged()
    {
        //  View of the component has not been updated at the time
        //  the DocumentEvent is fired

        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() ->
        {
            try
            {
                int endPos = component.getDocument().getLength();
                Rectangle rect = component.modelToView(endPos);

                if (rect != null && rect.y != lastHeight)
                {
                    setPreferredWidth();
                    repaint();
                    lastHeight = rect.y;
                }
            } catch (BadLocationException ex)
            { /* nothing to do */ }
        });
    }

    //
//  Implement PropertyChangeListener interface
//
    @Override
    public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent evt)
    {
        if (evt.getNewValue() instanceof Font)
        {
            if (updateFont)
            {
                Font newFont = (Font) evt.getNewValue();
                setFont(newFont);
                lastDigits = 0;
                setPreferredWidth();
            } else
            {
                repaint();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then line numbers can be added like this:

```
TextLineNumber textLineNumber = new TextLineNumber(sourceCodeArea);
sourceCodeAreaScrollPane.setRowHeaderView(textLineNumber);
```